# C++ list sorted by multiple fields at once

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm wondering if there's a good way to have a list of objects that is simultaneously sorted by two or more different criteria.   So, for example, if I had a class:

```
class Person {
    Person(const char *name, int age);
    float        age;
    char *       name;

    bool compareAge(person_t a) {return age < b.age;}
    bool compareName(person_t a) {return strcmp(name,a.name) < 0;}
};
```

And I have a million names.   I'm wondering if there's any commonly available class that can have a list of people, such that I could quickly iterate and search over this list either alphabetically, or by age.   So for example, I would like to be able to do the following without sorting between the lookups:

```
const std::multiset<Person, 2> mySet;
mySet.setSortCriteria(1, Person::compareName);
mySet.setSortCriteria(2, Person::compareAge);
populateAndSort(&mySet);

Person firstJohn = mySet.findByCriteria(1, Person("John",0));
Person firstTeen = mySet.findByCriteria(2, Person("",13));
```

I could do this with two separate sorted multisets of pointers to Person, but ideally, I'd like to maintain only a single list (so if I want to do lookups on say 20 criteria, I don't need to maintain 20 lists...).   I have not found any references so far on a good way to do this, however, at the moment I'm somewhat new to C++ and there's a good chance I'm missing something.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for a multi-index container.  Boost offers several of those.

Comment: Do you want a container that allows for a efficient search over multiple keys or you want to sort some objects on several fields? Because for the first one the sorting requirement is irrelevant.

Comment: Yes, indeed, Boost's mutli-index containers do what I'm looking for.   I had come across some boost lists, but managed to overlook the page describing these.   Thank you for pointing them out.   If you can post as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic in our poor world... If you want the same list to be accessible according to different sort orders, you will need to maintain multiple indexes. That's the way databases work: you generally have a primary key which is supposed to be the *native* access mode, and alternate indexes that allow quick searches and ordering on the index fields. In the container world, the primary key would be the native order of the primary container, and the alternate indexes would be alternate maps where the key if the field(s) used for ordering and the value would be an iterator on the primary container - at least for containers that do not invalid iterators on a change, like lists and maps.

You can roll your own. There are few caveats, mainly correctly maintain all indexes on a modification of the primary container. Or as you were advised in comments just use Boost.